# How to make C# WPF ComboBox, Calendar and DatePicker Controls TouchScreen respondent?

Tags: c#, touch, wpf-controls

I've been dealing many hours with the challenge of deploying a WPF application for Windows 10 PRO tablets.

My issue was to make `Button` controls touchable.  This was solved binding the properties `PreviewMouseDown`,  `PreviewMouseUp` and `TouchDown` to an event handler,  a click event.

However ComboBox, Calendar and Datepicker controls are a nightmare.  Haven't found how make them respond to touchscreen events.

There is no possibility of spending about $1,000 on libraries like Telerik, Xceed.  So just plain C#, XAML.  Also tried the Xceed Extended WPF toolkit,  but again it's controls don't respond to touchreen.  If this is correct how can it be implemented?

The possibility of using the Surface Toolkit is there as [this](http://nui.joshland.org/2010/04/why-wont-wpf-controls-work-with-touch.html) post states However haven't found examples of how to do it.  In the end I'm not dealing with Surface machines,  just Wondows 10 tablets.

My question is how can I make the DatePicker, Calendar and Combox respond to touchscreen on a Windows 10 Pro tablet.

Do I have to override an EventHndler to the controls,  instead of the native event? Click or change?

Answer (score -2):

Using AJAX control Toolkit you can overcome on this problem.
AJAX CALENDAR control bind this with textbox control ,and it will work finely with all devices.

Comment: Ajax calendar is a Telerik control and in my question is clear that Telerik and any paid library is out of scope.  On the other hand is a ASP.net lcontrol,  clearly I asked for WPF controls.